# How can I boot my system

Tags: boot, mount

I have to two operating systems in my computer, Ubuntu and XP. When I try to boot up  Ubuntu, I get the following message:

```
mount:mounting/dev on/root/dev failed:No such file or directory  
mount:mounting/sys on/root/sys failed:No such file or directory  
mount:mounting/proc on/root/proc failed:No such file or directory  
target file system doesn't have/sbin/init noinit found.try passing init=bootarg.  
busy boxv1.13.3(ubuntu 1.1.13.3-1ubuntu11)built-in shell(ash)enter'help'for alist of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

What can I do to boot up  Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD and open [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal).

Run this command: `sudo fdisk -l` (to get the device name):

```
radu@Radu: ~ > sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for radu: 

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x004aa9ec

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848    61431807    30356480    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        61432621   463410989   200989184+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       463410990   488392064    12490537+  83  Linux
/dev/sda5        61432623   450826239   194696808+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       450828288   463409151     6290432   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

In my case, my Ubuntu is on: `/dev/sda4`.

Run `sudo fsck /dev/sda4` (*you should change `/dev/sda4` with your device where is installed Ubuntu*). Restart the system and boot normally.

Sources: [How to Fix an Ubuntu Error: "No init found. Try passing init= bootarg"](http://pinoy-computing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-ubuntu-error-no-init-found.html).

Another related answers you can find here: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).